# Assign specific string of a specific line of a text file to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file where I know that the 16th line of the file will begin with `_____Dest : xxx`, where the underscores (5) are all spaces and xxx is not a known character length and may contain spaces. I want to assign xxx to a variable in a batch file. I imagine the code would contain a `for /f "skip=15 delims="` and a `find "Dest : "` in there, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it.

If it helps, I know that xxx will be a path that begins with `\\` and I want to include the `\\` in the variable.

Here is an excerpt from the file:

```
******************************************************************************* 
*                                                                             * 
* This is the robocopy log section.                                           * 
*                                                                             * 
******************************************************************************* 



-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Fri Dec 09 20:28:08 2016

   Source : \\server\path...
     Dest : \\server\path...

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /TEE /S /E /COPY:DAT /MT:128 /R:1 /W:1 

etc.
etc.
```

I want to assign everything on the 16th line after `Dest :` to a variable

Comment: When I try your suggestion and I substitute `your_filename` with the path and name of the file in question, I simply get `Echo is off` when I try to echo %content%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how I'd do it:

*This method means that there's no need to skip/count lines and only picks out the lines where the robocopy destination is a server path, (as per your specifications).*

```bat
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=\" %%A In ('Find "Dest : \\" ^<"file.ext"') Do Set "VAR=\\%%B"
```

Where file.ext is your robocopy output log.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "skip=15tokens=1*delims=: " %%a in (filename) do set "var=%%b"&goto done
:done
```

Where you'd need to "quote" any filename that contains separators, and if you use a quoted filename then you'll also need to include the `usebackq` parsing option before the `skip`.